# Find $u \in \mathbb C$ such that $\mathbb{Q}[u]=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{7},\sqrt{5},i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please, give-me a hint to solve this problem:

"Find $u \in \mathbb C$  such that $\mathbb{Q}[u]=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{7},\sqrt{5},i]$ and find also  the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Solution:

I've tried $\mathbb {Q}[\sqrt{35}+\sqrt{35}i]=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},i]$.

Proof:
It is obvious that $\mathbb {Q}[\sqrt{35}+\sqrt{35}i]\subseteq\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},i]$. 
Now,note that $i=\frac{1}{70}(\sqrt{35}+\sqrt{35}i)^2 \in \mathbb {Q}[\sqrt{35}+\sqrt{35}i]$. Is it possible to prove that $\sqrt{7},\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{35}+\sqrt{35}i]$?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is that $\sqrt {35}(1+i)$ will not do, because $\sqrt {35}=\sqrt 7\sqrt 5$ and there is no way to separate out the $\sqrt 5$ and $\sqrt 7$ - if you multiply by a rational, that doesn't work and if you square it you get an integer.

There are more sophisticated ways of answering - I waved my hands a bit there, but they would require the kind of insight which your question is trying to build. I wonder if you can think how you might add one simple element at a time to your field, and think about the degree of the extension and what that might mean for the degree of the polynomial you are expecting.

Comment: Good Evening,Mark! Ok, $[Q[\sqrt{7}]:Q]=2$ and $[Q[\sqrt{5}:Q]]=2$. Since gcd$\{2,2\}\neq 1$, what should be $[Q[\sqrt{7},\sqrt{5}]]$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{5}+i$$